# Why does Jesus refer to himself as "your Son" in John 17:1?

Tags: john

John 17:1 ESV "When Jesus had spoken these words, he lifted up his eyes to heaven, and said, "Father, the hour has come; glorify your Son that the Son may glorify you,".

Why does Jesus refer to himself as "your Son" here, but in John 17:4 referring to himself He does not continue in this way. From John 17:4 onwards He refers to Himself with "I" and "me".

John 17:4 "I have glorified you on earth, having accomplished the work that you gave me to do".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why does Jesus refer to himself as “your Son” in John 17:1?**

Adam the first human created by God,is a  "son of God".

Luke 3:38 NASB

> 38 The son of Enosh, the son of Seth, the son of Adam, the son of God.

Similarly, Jesus is called the "Son of God" because he was created with qualities like those of his Father.

John 1:14,49 NASB

The Word Made Flesh

> 14 And the Word became flesh, and dwelt among us; and we saw His
> glory, glory as of the only Son from the Father, full of grace and
> truth. 49 Nathanael answered  Him, “Rabbi, You are the Son of God; You
> are the King of Israel!”

Answer (score 3):

Why does Jesus refer to himself as “your Son” in John 17:1?

For emphasis.

Exodus 20:2

> "I am the LORD your God, who brought you out of Egypt, out of the land of slavery.

Later in Exodus 32:7, God was angry with the Israelites for worshipping the golden calf:

> Then the LORD said to Moses, "Go down, because **your people**, whom you brought up out of Egypt, have become corrupt.

Earlier, they were God's people. Now, they were Moses' people.

John 17:1

> After Jesus said this, he looked toward heaven and prayed: "Father, **the hour has come**. Glorify your Son, that your Son may glorify you.

This is it, Father. Glorify your Son on the cross, entailing all the insults, pains, sufferings, and death. I'm your Son who is going to take on the sins of the world.

The emphasis is on the Father: I am your son.

Pulpit explains:

> It is very noticeable that he speaks of himself in the **third** person. This is justified by the fact that he here conspicuously rises out of himself into the consciousness of God, and **loses himself in the Father**. The glorification of the Son is first of all by death issuing in life. He was crowned with glory in order that he might taste death for every man. The conflict, the victorious combat with death, was the beginning of his glory. In taking upon himself all the burden of human sorrow, and exhausting the poison of the sting of death, he would "glorify God"

Answer (score 2):

To answer that, let's take a look at the other verses.

Who does our Lord Jesus Christ introduce in verse 3?

> **John 17:3 (NKJV)**
>
> "And this is eternal life, that they may know **You, the only true God**,
> and Jesus Christ whom You have sent."

Who does our Lord Jesus Christ introduce in verse 3? Jesus said, "the only true God". Did our Lord Jesus Christ introduce Himself as the true God? Jesus clarified, "that they may know You".

Who does Christ refer to as 'You, the only true God'?

> **John 17:1 (NKJV)**
>
> "Jesus spoke these words, lifted up His eyes to heaven, and said:
> '**Father**, the hour has come. Glorify Your Son, that Your Son also may
> glorify You,"

Who does Christ refer to as 'You, the only true God'? Jesus said, "Father". How does Jesus refer to Himself? Jesus said, "Your Son". Jesus is making clear that He is the Son and not the Father, so as to leave no doubt as to whom He is referring to as the only true God—not Himself, but rather the Father.

How does Jesus refer to Himself in the verses after?

> **John 17:4 (NKJV)**
>
> "**I** have glorified You on the earth. I have finished the work which You
> have given **Me** to do."

How does Jesus refer to Himself in the verses after? Jesus said, "I [...] Me". Now that Christ has already given us clear distinction between Himself (the Son) and the one true God (the Father), He no longer needs to speak in the third-person.